# Regex to convert Get request objects to CSS objects

Tags: php, regex

Given a string of items in the request object like...

```
mytheme_color|body = '000000'
mytheme_color|h1 = 'ffffff'
mytheme_color.footer|a = 'cccccc'
mytheme_color.menu.top|a = 'ff0000'
mytheme_color.content|ul|li#test = '777777'
```

What would the regex and PHP look like to take each item and write them to an output string that could then be saved as a file named custom.css, so that the final contents of the file is...

```
body {color:#000000;}
h1 {color:#ffffff;}
.footer a {color:#cccccc;}
.menu.top a {color:#ff0000;}
.content ul li#test {color:#777777;}
```

Note: pipe in request should just be converted to empty space for output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the input data is, as described above, a single string with the values seperated by line breaks then the following preg_match_all and loop will work to create a string called $strCssFile which can be written out to a CSS file:

```
<?php

// Test dummy data
$strTest = "mytheme_color|body = '000000'
mytheme_color|h1 = 'ffffff'
mytheme_color.footer|a = 'cccccc'
mytheme_color.menu.top|a = 'ff0000'
mytheme_color.content|ul|li#test = '777777'";

$arrOutput = array();
preg_match_all("/mytheme_color([a-z0-9#\.|]+) = '([a-f0-9]+)'/i", $strTest, $arrOutput);
//preg_match_all("/mytheme_color([a-z0-9#\*|]+) = '([a-f0-9]+)'/i", $strTest, $arrOutput);

$strCssLine = '';
$strCssFile = '';

foreach ($arrOutput[1] as $intKey => $strValue) {
    $strCssLine = trim(str_replace('|', ' ', $strValue));
    //$strCssLine = trim(str_replace(array('|', '*'), array(' ', '.'), $strValue));
    $strCssLine .= ' { color: ';
    $strCssLine .= $arrOutput[2][$intKey];
    $strCssLine .= "; }\n";
    $strCssFile .= $strCssLine;
}

echo $strCssFile;

?>
```

Comment: This looks great. However, in the course of echo'ing out my option values, is appears that using a dot "." in the option name foobars the array I'm using to send the options to my save function. What would the code look like if you sub an asterisk "*" for the period "."?

Comment: If you mean changing the input data from this style format "mytheme_color.footer" to this one "mytheme_color*footer", I've updated the above code with two commented lines.  Swap them for the lines that appear immediately above them for the new format.